# Converting values of a sub key of a Json into array in Java

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, org.json

if I have to following XML document info into a string:

```xml
<Collection>
  ...
  <Places><D>USA</D><D>BRAZIL</D><D>COREA</D></Places>
  ...
</Collection>
```

and I want to convert it into a Json that look something like:

```
{
  "PLACES": ["USA", "BRAZIL", "COREA"]
}
```

Note that the `<D>` tags are ignored and i get the values inside of them as the values that I want into my array... How do I do that in java? I'm doing the following using org.json and jackson API:

```java
String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(file.getAbsolutePath())); 
JSONObject json = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(xml);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
Object json2 = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), Object.class);
String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(json2);
System.out.println(output);
```

but it converts the info like this:

```
{
 "PLACES" : {
    "D" : [ "USA", "BRAZIL", "COREA" ]
  }
```

So I want the array to be directly after "PLACES", ignoring that "D"... any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: *"any suggestion?"* Yes, write code to change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `XmlMapper` to convert xml into POJO. Even you don't need to read file manually.

**POJO (Collection class)**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Collection")
public class Collection {

    @JsonProperty("PLACES")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "D")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Places")
    List<String> places;

    public List<String> getPlaces() {
        return places;
    }

    public void setPlaces(List<String> places) {
        this.places = places;
    } 
}
```

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[]  args) throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    Collection c = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("/root/config.txt"), Collection.class);
    System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(c));

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(c));
}
```

**Output**

```
<Collection>
  <Places>
    <D>USA</D>
    <D>BRAZIL</D>
    <D>COREA</D>
  </Places>
</Collection>

{
  "PLACES" : [ "USA", "BRAZIL", "COREA" ]
}
```

**Xml library**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml and Gson can do it:

```
public class Collection {
    public Places Places;
}
public class Places {
    @SerializedName("PLACES")
    public List<String> D;
}

final String data = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Collection c = simple.fromXml(data, Collection.class);

final Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(c.Places));
```

Will output:

```
{"PLACES":["USA","BRAZIL","COREA"]}
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW if you don't like the naming you can change anything using SimpleXml annotations. I didn't need them so I didn't use them.